# Estimate memory requirements for tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I estimate the memory requirements of my tensorflow model? Should the below give a somewhat accurate representation?

```
size = 0
for variable in tf.all_variables():
    size += int(np.prod(variable.get_shape()))

print(size)
```

`size` should be the number of variables. Should `size * dtype` then be an estimate of memory requirements?

Answer (score 0):

No, you also have to account for your other tensors (e.g. `tf.placeholder` and `tf.constant`), and you should also have room for the gradients, as I believe a bunch of values are cached during the forward pass so that backprop doesn't become too slow.